# How to change the text color of a Tooltip in Blender

Tags: interface, accessibility

To try and improve readability of a tooltip, I would like to tint the "keymap" after eacht line to a different tint. Thusfar I have been unable to find a solution for this.

This is the Code that I am using:

```
@classmethod
def description(cls, context, event):
        return  f"Setup UV's and unwrap using a specified method:\n"\
                f"• Setup UV0_SWATCH\n"\
                f"• Setup UV1_LIGHTMAP  Alt"\
                f"• Setup UV2_TILING  Ctrl\n"\
                f"• Setup UV3_VIEW  Ctrl + Alt"
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

And this is how I would like it to look like:

[image]

I Do know that there are some color values in Blender that might be accessible, like the one for a chosen enum,(At Center) but I have not been able to see anyone try to use this to their advantage... if it is even possible.

[image]

Anyone that could steer me in the right direction I would be very gratefull.